# How to store cookie variables in Safari and Edge?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, safari, microsoft-edge

JavaScript used to store cookies:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=<?= site_url() ?>Portal/";
    //Cookies.set(cname, cvalue, { expires: expires });
}
```

PHP:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["apikey"])) 
{
    redirect('/Login', 'refresh');  
}
```

The above code is working in all browsers, except Edge and Safari.

Comment: may be issue in safari is limit of storing data size.

Comment: Are you in private mode?

Comment: The `path` value should probably just be `/Portal/` - you don't want the domain in there.